# Different order of computations for nested Do

Tags: programming

When I use

```
Do[Print[{a, b}],{a, 0, 2},{b, 0, 2}]
```

then I (correctly) obtain

```
{0, 0} {0, 1} {0, 2} {1, 0} {1, 1} {1, 2} {2, 0} {2, 1} {2, 2}
```

However, I would like something like:

```
{0, 0} {0, 1} {1, 0} {0, 2} {1, 1} {2, 0} {1, 2} {2, 1} {2, 2}
```

That is, I want to *prioritize* calculations for which $a+b$ is small.

Is there any simple way to achieve this within the `Do` Command?

Comment: Maybe `Do[Print[{a, t - a}], {t, 0, 4}, {a, Max[0, t - 2], Min[t, 2]}]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Interesting approach, that is really helpful. Note that it generalizes to more variables by `Do[Print[{a, s - a, t - s}], {t, 0, 6}, {s, Max[0, t - 2], 
  Min[t, 4]}, {a, Max[0, s - 2], Min[s, 2]}]`, `Do[Print[{a, s - a, t - s, u - t}], {u, 0, 8}, {t, Max[0, u - 2], 
  Min[u, 6]}, {s, Max[0, t - 2], Min[t, 4]}, {a, Max[0, s - 2], 
  Min[s, 2]}]` etcetera

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this doesn't seem like a very natural action to take with `Do`, which requires a fixed iterator specification.

Rather, you can construct a list with [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) (note that the syntax is very similar to `Do`) :

```
Table[{a, b}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}]
```

> {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}}

You can convert this to a list of tuples with [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html):

```
Flatten[%, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
> ```

Then sort it according to the sum of the list elements:

```
sortedList = SortBy[%, Total]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
> ```

Finally, you can iterate over the elements in this list using [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) :

```
Scan[Print, %]
```

---

**Edit** :  It's worth mentioning that it's possible to use `Do` rather than `Scan` in the last line, but `Scan` is really a better fit here.

If you insist upon using `Do`, you can do

```
Do[Print[x], {x, sortedList}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will consider this, however I do not really like the idea of a possibly large sortedList sitting inside my ram.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate zig-zag ordered indices dynamically, without generating all possible values first.

Here is a simple zig-zag algorithm adopted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28570193).
It should be optimized if the speed is a concern.

Function `zigZagOrdering` converts an integer `index` (from `0` to `lengthA*lengthB-1`)
into the values of `a` (from `0` to `lengthA-1`) and `b` (from `0` to `lengthB-1`).

```
ClearAll[zigZagOrdering];
zigZagOrdering = Compile[{{lengthA, _Integer}, {lengthB, _Integer}, {index, _Integer}},
Module[{dx = 1, dy = -1, a=0, b=0},
    Do[
        a = a + dy;
        b = b + dx;
        If[a<0||b<0||a>=lengthA||b>=lengthB, {dx,dy} = {dy,dx}];
        If[a>=lengthA, a=lengthA-1; b=b+2];
        If[b>=lengthB, b=lengthB-1; a=a+2];
        If[a<0, a=0];
        If[b<0, b=0],
        {i, 0, index-1}];
    {a,b}
    ]]
```

This function can be used as follows:

```
Module[{lengthA=3, lengthB=3, a, b},
    Do[
        {a,b} = zigZagOrdering[lengthA, lengthB, index];
        Print[{a,b}],
        {index, 0, lengthA*lengthB-1}
        ];
    ]
```

> ```
> {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}, {2,0}, {1,1}, {0,2}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {2,2}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind ultimately over a slightly bigger domain. (For example if you plan on aborting at some stage anyway) you can simply redefine you indices `A=a+b` and `b`

```
Do[Print[{A-b,b}],{A,0,4},{b,0,2}]
```

if you want to restrict to the same square domain

```
Do[Print[{(A-b),b}],{A,0,4},{B, Max[0,A-2] , Min[2,A]}]
```

Comment: I very much like this method's simplicity, but I think it needs some refinement.  The first code can be vastly improved by replacing `{B,-A,A}` with `{B,-A,A,2}` -- this eliminates all the fractions.  (As a bonus, you can restrict to exactly the desired output by checking that `a<=2&&b<=2` in the body of `Do`.)  Moreover, your second method doesn't work.  It misses `{2,0}`, for example.

Comment: corrected the bounds. Works perfectly now

Comment: You still need to replace `B` with `b` in the iterator specification for your second method.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the second method is now extremely similar to [CarlWoll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146902/different-order-of-computations-for-nested-do/146934#comment394799_146902).

Answer (score 0):

```
all[{i_Integer}] := Sequence @@ {{0, i}, {i, 0}}
all[{i_Integer, i_Integer}] := {i, i}
all[{i_Integer, j_Integer}] := Sequence @@ {{i, j}, {j, i}}
Do[Print /@ all /@ IntegerPartitions[i, 2, Range[3]], {i, 1, 7}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SortBy[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 2], Total]

{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2,2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your list and then:

```
SortBy[mylist, Norm]
```

Comment: Reasonable approach that gives `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {2,  1}}`.  Similar but not identical to what was suggested in the question.